# Google sheets converts 01/01/0001 into 01/01/2001

Tags: date, google-sheets, formatting, string-formatting, number-formatting

How to make it stops? Tried many different formattings and it gives no difference. Could not find anything in settings. Googling only gives how to stop google sheets from auto-formatting numbers into dates, which is not the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

also you could use:

```
="01/01/0001"
```

to calculate the age vertically try:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(REGEXEXTRACT(B1:B2, "\d{4}")*{-1; 1})
```

[image]

or horizontally:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(REGEXEXTRACT(A11:B11, "\d{4}")*{-1, 1})
```

[image]

Comment: How can i compute with this? For example if i want to know the age of someone born in 2/06/0001 and died 01/03/0092

Comment: @Zaizerzazza answer updated

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to edit the number after setting the format as text. Below is an example of what I mean:

[image: ex]